# Form on website does not input information to database after redirection

Tags: php, forms

I have a form on my site that is supposed to send information to a database and then send the users to a page that thanks them for contacting us.

Here is the form section of my page:

```
<form class="col s12" action="become-devplateau-developer-thankyou" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="input-field col m6 s12">
                        <input id="first_name" name="first_name" type="text" class="validate" required>
                        <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-field col m6 s12">
                        <input id="last_name" name="last_name" type="text" class="validate" required>
                        <label for="last_name">Last Name</label>
                    </div>
                     <div class="input-field col m6 s12">
                        <i class="mdi-content-mail prefix"></i>
                        <input id="email" type="email" name="email" class="validate" required>
                        <center><label for="email">Email</label></center>
                    </div>
                </div>

                  <div class="row">

        <div class="row">
           <label>Upload your resume</label>
           <div class="file-field input-field">

              <div class="btn">
                 <span>Browse</span>
                 <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
              </div>
              <div class="file-path-wrapper">
                 <input class="file-path validate" type="text" placeholder="Upload file">
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>


                     <p class="right-align"><button class="btn btn-large waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" id="btn-apply" name="btn-apply">Apply Now</button></p>


  </div>
            </form>
```

The action in the form is where I am redirecting this page too, "become-devplateau-developer-thankyou" is a page in website directory.

Here is the php section I am trying to use to send the information from my form to my database:

```
if (isset($_POST['btn-apply'])) {
    $first_name = strip_tags($_POST['first_name']);
    $last_name = strip_tags($_POST['last_name']);
    $email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
    $target_dir = "uploads/";
    // $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    $fdate=date("Y-m-d-H-i-s");
    $filename = $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"];
    $filename2 = $email . $filename . $fdate;
    //$file_tmp = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'];
    // move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"uploads/".$filename);
    $uploadOk = 1;
    // $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    try
      {
        $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO developerapplications(email,first_name,last_name,fname)
                                                     VALUES(:email, :first_name, :last_name, :fname)");
        $stmt->bindparam(":email", $email);
        $stmt->bindparam(":first_name", $first_name);
        $stmt->bindparam(":last_name", $last_name);
        $stmt->bindparam(":fname", $filename2);
        $stmt->execute();

        return $stmt;
      }
      catch(PDOException $e)
      {
        echo $e->getMessage();
      }

}
```

These are on the same page as of now and it will redirect properly but will not send the information to the database. I have tried moving the code to process the information to the database on become-devplateau-developer-thankyou, but then it does not show the page with the message thanking the user for submitting the form.

I would like to keep this all in php and html/css if possible. Alot of what I have seen starts to involve javascript or something else.

Can anyone assist me in figuring out the best way to do this?

Comment: Have you checked your error logs?

Comment: `return $stmt;`? Is the entire PHP code inside any function?

Comment: I suppose that $_POST doesn't contain **btn-apply**. You should remove name attr from the button and add a hidden input `<input name='btn-apply' type='hidden' value='' />`

Comment: @JayBlanchard yes I have, nothing there.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul I am not sure what you mean. Sorry. I have only recently started helping to get things like these working on the website.

Comment: @Talgat I was under the impression that $_POST did contain btn-apply. If it does not, I'm sorry. I can just add <input name='btn-apply' type=hidden' value='' /> under <p class="right-align"><button class="btn btn-large waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" id="btn-apply" name="btn-apply">Apply Now</button></p>? and then have if(isset($_POST['btn-apply'])) in the php?

Comment: @RaspberryRye form sends data from input fields. Instead of button you should use `<input class="btn btn-large waves-effect waves-light" id="btn-apply" name="btn-apply" type="button" value="Apply Now" />` Also you should check other fields exist otherwise you will get a notice "Undefined index".

Comment: @Talgat Thank you for the advice, but now the button does not do anything with using <input>. All of the other fields exist.

Comment: @RaspberryRye try to change type to submit `<input class="btn btn-large waves-effect waves-light" id="btn-apply" name="btn-apply" type="submit" value="Apply Now" />` or use the previous solution with button and hidden input. And you can't be sure that other fields exist because someone could make a custom post request to your server.

Comment: @Talgat Thank you, the button works now. :) Still does not help with what I was trying to get working. The information on the contact page does not input to the database. Thank you again though.

Comment: @RaspberryRye As I can see you send data to 'become-devplateau-developer-thankyou' and should use your php code there. Or you should change the **action** attr to the page where your php code now. And add `header("Location: http://www.example.com/");` to your thankyou page.

Comment: @Talgat I have tried using the php code on my 'become-devplateau-developer-thankyou' page, it will send the information to the database but then it will not show the message thanking the user for contacting us. Sorry if I did not make that clear before. I will try adding the header to my thank you page, it would be header("Location: http://www.devplateau.com/become-devplateau-developer-thankyou"? Also, I'm sorry if this sounds stupid, but in the input tag for the button can I do some type of align? I have tried with css but that does not seem to work.

Comment: @RaspberryRye Where is your php code now? Change form action attr to this page. Then place `header("Location: http://www.devplateau.com/become-devplateau-developer-thankyou");` instead of `return $stmt;`

Comment: @Talgat I changed the action attribute to the page the code is on and have placed the header in it. When I fill out the form to test it, the page redirects to a sorry page I have set like it cannot access the thank you page for some reason.

Comment: @RaspberryRye I'm sorry. There were wrong letters. `header("Location: http://www.devplateau.com/become-devplateau-developer-thankyou");`

Comment: @Talgat haha, I didn't even notice. Though, still does work. I have checked the spelling again and it all seems right.

Comment: Try this header("Location: http://www.devplateau.com/become-devplateau-developer-thankyou"); It seems like stackoverflow breaks the link when I format it as a code.

Comment: @Talgat Thank you so much! That worked :) One last question, and this may seem a bit silly to ask, but what is an easy way to get the submit button now to be on the right? I tried changing my css file but that did not seem to do anything.

Comment: @RaspberryRye Wrap **<i class="btn btn-large...** with <div class="col s12 right-align"><i class="btn btn-large...

Comment: @Talgat Thank you so much :)